# Adding a variable in a VLookUp

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

I'm having a problem with a vlookup function. First code shows that vlookup know what is "TempArg'17", but now I want to change it this text to string and write it inside vlookup, so I created a string temp.

```
Dim temp As String
Dim num As Int
num = 17

temp = "TempArg" + "'" + Cstr(num)
```

Here is the old code that works:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "Številka]],'TempArg''17'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"
```

And here is the code that I want to change and that doesn't work:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "Številka]],temp'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whare the two column in the lookup range?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

`"=VLOOKUP([@[" & Chr(10) & "Številka]],'" & temp & "'!C[-16]:C[-17],2,FALSE)"`

Comment: might need a `'` on the left side of temp.

Comment: Thanks, but it says "Syntax Error" :-/